# What's the best way to handle touch actions in order to add multiple objects to a scene?

Tags: swift, scenekit, arkit

I want to add multiple objects to a scene, but I can't seem to wrap my head against how to access the different, unordered positions, of a set with `touches: Set<UITouch>`

Is there a more efficient way to handle adding object requests one at a time after each specific screen touch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a gesture recognizer, get the currentLocation (of the tap), then un-project the 2D screen coordinates to 3D world space.  scenePoint contains the vector you need.  This will work if you are looking down the -Z axis, with Y up.

```
var currentLocation = CGPoint.zero

 @objc func handleTap(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer)
        {
            currentLocation = recognizer.location(in: gameScene)
            let projectedPoint = gameScene.projectPoint(SCNVector3(0, 0, 0))
            let scenePoint = gameScene.unprojectPoint(SCNVector3(currentLocation.x, currentLocation.y, CGFloat(projectedPoint.z)))
            {
                placeObject(vPosition: scenePoint)
            }
        }
```